# Movie with ogre-like creatures that capture humans

Tags: story-identification

The only scene I remember is a bunch of humans being let out of somewhere so that the ogre-like creatures can see what they eat over a cctv I think. At one point a human finds a rat and starts eating it immediately. One ogre creature responds to this by saying something like "eww, don't they want to cook it first."

That's all I can remember.

Comment: The reason you don't remember more of the plot is because it was soo bad you drank yourself unconscious to wipe out the memories of it (You did the right thing, it was really bad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a scene from [Battlefield Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlefield_Earth_(film)).

The human the main Psychlos captured is starving. So he allows it to escape with some friends and it catches a rat to eat, and they eat it raw, because they are afraid to start a fire.

[image]

So the Psychlos recapture them and feed them rats.

This scene happens later, because the idiot Psychlos believe rats are a delicacy among humans.

The official trailer: